# IE 8 not displaying navigation bar

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

http://www.newpathwaysretreat.com

I have been informed that this site is not working properly with IE8, the navigation bar is not showing up and the links which normally go across horizontally are now just an unstyled list in the top left corner.

Any help would be appreciated!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar's styles are wrapped in `@media screen` which IE8 and below basically do not understand.

Comment: You could either remove the wrapping media query if it's unnecessary in your scenario, or add media="screen" in the link tag

Answer (score 0):

The `<nav>` tag isn't supported in IE8.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp

Basically if a tag was added in HTML5 assume that IE8 isn't going to support it. That's part of the reason there's an IE9.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I was able to find the solution based on your answer!

Comment: I personally would wrap it in a div and use a CSS conditional comment to apply formatting if IE version 8 or less to keep from having to lose the great functionality of the `<nav>` tag. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html for some good examples of CSS conditional commenting.

Comment: There may be a better way that's just one way off the top of my head. Formatting something to work in IE can be a pain and I've frequently used conditional comments to check for IE or IE version.